# How to read an external form redirect?

Tags: forms, vue.js, redirect, post

I'm currently working on a VueJS project on which I've just implemented a SSO system designed by the Portuguese government using our national identity cards, but I'm having some issues parsing the response from the external authentication server.

Here's a small GIF of my problem: https://gfycat.com/threadbarepossiblebagworm

The workflow is as follows:

1. User clicks on Authenticate.
2. User chooses "Login via ID Card"
3. User gets redirected to the external Authentication Provider
4. User logins with his ID Card.
5. External Authentication provider then sends back a POST method to the callback URL that is provided.
6. I read/parse the callback

The issue lies in step 6... The external authentication provider uses the callback URL I provided but I get this error

```
Cannot POST /users/callback
```

If this was a typical NodeJS I could just use

```
router.post('/callback' ....)
```

Is there a way I can read that callback in VueJS?

I've found this similar issue https://forum.vuejs.org/t/cannot-post-handling-form-post-from-an-external-site/41194/1 but no one managed to offer him a solution.

​

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Before you ask, yes, that '/users/callback' is defined on router.ts and if I go to that route it does show a page. It's just not designed for POST methods afaik

Comment: Update the server to `GET` the callback instead of `POST`.

Comment: The identity provider only uses the POST binding. I cannot change the callback binding to GET sadly

Answer (score 0):

Vue is a front-end framework, which means it doesn't have direct access to POST requests by default.

For production, are you running an npm script like "npm run build"  and then serving the files that appear in the "dist" folder on a webserver, say Apache? Then you would have to respond to the POST request in Apache.

You could then store their authentication result "farther toward the backend" than Vue and have Vue grab it with vuex.